# SVG paths and images

Tags: javascript, html, css, svg

I'm trying to add images to SVG paths as the title is saying.

I've made the following fiddle,
[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/w9ax412L/)

I'd like to put images within the paths, like so,
(Green dots representing images)
[so image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u0w63.png)

How would this be done? I tried adding images to the path, but they just didn't show up, obviously.

Code:

```
<svg width="175" height="175">
  <g transform="translate(87.5,87.5)">
    <path fill="#1f77b4" d="M5.357829746269671e-15,-87.5L3.949485927250214e-15,-64.5Z"></path>
    <path fill="#aec7e8" d="M5.357829746269671e-15,-87.5L3.949485927250214e-15,-64.5Z"></path>
    <path fill="#ff7f0e" d="M5.357829746269671e-15,-87.5L3.949485927250214e-15,-64.5Z"></path>
    <path fill="#ffbb78" d="M5.357829746269671e-15,-87.5L3.949485927250214e-15,-64.5Z"></path>
    <path fill="#2ca02c" d="M5.357829746269671e-15,-87.5L3.949485927250214e-15,-64.5Z"></path>
    <path fill="#98df8a" d="M5.357829746269671e-15,-87.5A87.5,87.5,0,0,1,83.21744517582593,-27.038987007807897L61.3431453010374,-19.93159613718411A64.5,64.5,0,0,0,3.949485927250214e-15,-64.5Z"></path>
    <path fill="#d62728" d="M83.21744517582593,-27.038987007807897A87.5,87.5,0,0,1,51.4312095755914,70.7889870078079L37.91214877286452,52.18159613718411A64.5,64.5,0,0,0,61.3431453010374,-19.93159613718411Z"></path>
    <path fill="#ff9896" d="M51.4312095755914,70.7889870078079A87.5,87.5,0,0,1,-51.43120957559139,70.7889870078079L-37.91214877286451,52.18159613718411A64.5,64.5,0,0,0,37.91214877286452,52.18159613718411Z"></path>
    <path fill="#9467bd" d="M-51.43120957559139,70.7889870078079A87.5,87.5,0,0,1,-83.21744517582594,-27.038987007807886L-61.34314530103741,-19.9315961371841A64.5,64.5,0,0,0,-37.91214877286451,52.18159613718411Z"></path>
    <path fill="#c5b0d5" d="M-83.21744517582594,-27.038987007807886A87.5,87.5,0,0,1,-1.607348923880901e-14,-87.5L-1.1848457781750641e-14,-64.5A64.5,64.5,0,0,0,-61.34314530103741,-19.9315961371841Z"></path>
  </g>
</svg>
```

Comment: Read up on [patterns](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/pservers.html#Patterns).

Comment: Do you mean additional SVG elements or actual bitmap images?

Answer (score 1):

Following the picture, you need to add 5 circles.

Each circle is rotated relative to the other by the same angle - `360/5 = 72`

- Create the first circle:

`<defs>
 <circle id="greenCircle" cx="13" cy="98"  r="10" fill="#B6FF00" /> 
 </defs>`

- Use the command `<use>` to clone the circle and rotate it `transform
  =" rotate (deg x y) "` to the desired angle relative to the first circle.

```html
 
 <svg width="175" height="175" > 
 <defs>
 <circle id="greenCircle" cx="13" cy="98"  r="10" fill="#B6FF00" /> 
 </defs>
  <g transform="translate(87.5,87.5)">
    <path fill="#1f77b4" d="M5.357829746269671e-15,-87.5L3.949485927250214e-15,-64.5Z"></path>
    <path fill="#aec7e8" d="M5.357829746269671e-15,-87.5L3.949485927250214e-15,-64.5Z"></path>
    <path fill="#ff7f0e" d="M5.357829746269671e-15,-87.5L3.949485927250214e-15,-64.5Z"></path>
    <path fill="#ffbb78" d="M5.357829746269671e-15,-87.5L3.949485927250214e-15,-64.5Z"></path>
    <path fill="#2ca02c" d="M5.357829746269671e-15,-87.5L3.949485927250214e-15,-64.5Z"></path>
    <path fill="#98df8a" d="M5.357829746269671e-15,-87.5A87.5,87.5,0,0,1,83.21744517582593,-27.038987007807897L61.3431453010374,-19.93159613718411A64.5,64.5,0,0,0,3.949485927250214e-15,-64.5Z"></path>
    <path fill="#d62728" d="M83.21744517582593,-27.038987007807897A87.5,87.5,0,0,1,51.4312095755914,70.7889870078079L37.91214877286452,52.18159613718411A64.5,64.5,0,0,0,61.3431453010374,-19.93159613718411Z"></path>
    <path fill="#ff9896" d="M51.4312095755914,70.7889870078079A87.5,87.5,0,0,1,-51.43120957559139,70.7889870078079L-37.91214877286451,52.18159613718411A64.5,64.5,0,0,0,37.91214877286452,52.18159613718411Z"></path>
    <path fill="#9467bd" d="M-51.43120957559139,70.7889870078079A87.5,87.5,0,0,1,-83.21744517582594,-27.038987007807886L-61.34314530103741,-19.9315961371841A64.5,64.5,0,0,0,-37.91214877286451,52.18159613718411Z"></path>
    <path fill="#c5b0d5" d="M-83.21744517582594,-27.038987007807886A87.5,87.5,0,0,1,-1.607348923880901e-14,-87.5L-1.1848457781750641e-14,-64.5A64.5,64.5,0,0,0,-61.34314530103741,-19.9315961371841Z"></path>
  </g> 
  
<use xlink:href="#greenCircle"  transform="rotate(-10 87.5 87.5)" /> 
<use xlink:href="#greenCircle"  transform="rotate(62 87.5 87.5)" /> 
<use xlink:href="#greenCircle"  transform="rotate(134 87.5 87.5)" /> 
<use xlink:href="#greenCircle"  transform="rotate(206 87.5 87.5)" /> 
<use xlink:href="#greenCircle"  transform="rotate(278 87.5 87.5)" />  

</svg>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a hint, add this to your fiddle:

```
<circle cx="0" cy="0" r="10" fill="#12345"></circle>
```

Comment: Oops, looks like the code got lost:

`<circle cx="0" cy="0" r="10" fill="#12345"></circle>`